# Making a simple Text-Based RPG is harder than expected

Tags: java, if-statement, notepad++, javac

Sooooo... I am in the progress of building a text based RPG with JAVA, and something is wrong....
It will compile, It'll run, but... well, it's hard to explain. I'll put the code  up first.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class XOBYT
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String choice;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("COPYRIGHT 2016 HARBNGER STUDIOS\nYou wake up in a broken-down alabaster\nhouse with no knowledge of who\nyou are or where you came from.\nWhich direction do you want to head? (options: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST)");
        choice = scan.nextLine();{
            if(choice.equals("NORTH")){System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED NORTH TO A RUN-DOWN VILLAGE. CARCASSES EVERYWHERE.\nNO SURVIVORS. I WONDER WHAT HAPPENED HERE.\nI LOOTED THE BODIES, TALOS BLESS MY SOUL. I FOUND A PISTOL AND SOME GAUZE. I CAN VIEW MY INVENTORY, HIT THE ROAD, OR LINGER AROUND.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,ROAD,LINGER)");}
            choice = scan.nextLine();{
                if(choice.equals("INVENTORY")){
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644\n\nI TRAVELED SOUTH AND STOPPED AT AN ABANDONED\nOUTPOST. IT HAS SOME SUPPLIES. I PICKED\nUP A PISTOL AND SOME NANITE SYRINGES. I CAN CHECK\nMY INVENTORY, MOVE FARTHER SOUTH, OR EXPLORE.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,FARTHER,EXPLORE)");}
                choice = scan.nextLine();{
                }
                if(choice.equals("FARTHER")){
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED EAST AND STOPPED BY A DIRTY STREAM.\nIT'S FILLED WITH GARBAGE, BUT THERE ARE ALSO PLASTIC BOTTLES.\nSHOULD I FILL THEM WITH WATER OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: FILL,MOVE)");}
                choice = scan.nextLine();{
                }
                if(choice.equals("EXPLORE")){
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED WEST AND FOUND AN ABANDONED SHACK.\nSHOULD I SEARCH IT FOR LOOT OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: SEARCH,MOVE)");}}
                choice = scan.nextLine();{}

            if(choice.equals("SOUTH")){
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644\n\nI TRAVELED SOUTH AND STOPPED AT AN ABANDONED\nOUTPOST. IT HAS SOME SUPPLIES. I PICKED\nUP A PISTOL AND SOME NANITE SYRINGES. I CAN CHECK\nMY INVENTORY, MOVE FARTHER SOUTH, OR EXPLORE.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,FARTHER,EXPLORE)");}
            choice = scan.nextLine();{
            }
            if(choice.equals("EAST")){
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED EAST AND STOPPED BY A DIRTY STREAM.\nIT'S FILLED WITH GARBAGE, BUT THERE ARE ALSO PLASTIC BOTTLES.\nSHOULD I FILL THEM WITH WATER OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: FILL,MOVE)");}
            choice = scan.nextLine();{
            }
            if(choice.equals("WEST")){
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED WEST AND FOUND AN ABANDONED SHACK.\nSHOULD I SEARCH IT FOR LOOT OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: SEARCH,MOVE)");}}
            choice = scan.nextLine();{
            }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure it out, but i think the "if" statements are conflicting with each other. when I run it, type "NORTH", and then type either "FARTHER" or "EXPLORE", The Command Prompt goes blank. It doesn't do what it's supposed to... Except when you type "INVENTORY". It then works perfectly. It happens again if i switch the places of "choice equals INVENTORY" with any other "Choice equals," except then it'll be, again, the top "if" statement. I'm typing this on Notepad++ and compiling via Command prompt. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: According to some comments, I forgot that I neglected to add that I am semi-rusty to java, and that I need specifics. If you can, walk me through it like a baby. If it's too big of a hassle, skip my question.

EDIT: I deleted most of the unneeded brackets. If I still have some, please tell me. Here is what I have, and it runs and compiles almost perfectly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class XOBYT
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String choice;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("COPYRIGHT 2016 HARBNGER STUDIOSYou wake up in a broken-down alabaster\nhouse with no knowladge of who\nyou are or where you came from.\nWhich direction do you want to head? (options: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST)");

       choice = scan.nextLine();
       if(choice.equals("NORTH")){
               System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED NORTH TO A RUN-DOWN VILLAGE. CARCASSES EVERYWHERE.\nNO SURVIVORS. I WONDER WHAT HAPPENED HERE.\nI LOOTED THE BODIES, TALOS BLESS MY SOUL. I FOUND A PISTOL AND SOME GAUZE. I CAN VIEW MY INVENTORY, HIT THE ROAD, OR LINGER AROUND.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,ROAD,LINGER)");
       }

       choice = scan.nextLine();
       if(choice.equals("INVENTORY")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644\n\nI TRAVELED SOUTH AND STOPPED AT AN ABANDONED\nOUTPOST. IT HAS SOME SUPPLIES. I PICKED\nUP A PISTOL AND SOME NANITE SYRINGES. I CAN CHECK\nMY INVENTORY, MOVE FARTHER SOUTH, OR EXPLORE.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,FARTHER,EXPLORE)");
       }

       choice = scan.nextLine();
       if(choice.equals("FARTHER")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED EAST AND STOPPED BY A DIRTY STREAM.\nIT'S FILLED WITH GARBAGE, BUT THERE ARE ALSO PLASTIC BOTTLES.\nSHOULD I FILL THEM WITH WATER OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: FILL,MOVE)");
       }

       choice = scan.nextLine();
       if(choice.equals("EXPLORE")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED WEST AND FOUND AN ABANDONED SHACK.\nSHOULD I SEARCH IT FOR LOOT OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: SEARCH,MOVE)");
       }

       choice = scan.nextLine();
       if(choice.equals("SOUTH")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644\n\nI TRAVELED SOUTH AND STOPPED AT AN ABANDONED\nOUTPOST. IT HAS SOME SUPPLIES. I PICKED\nUP A PISTOL AND SOME NANITE SYRINGES. I CAN CHECK\nMY INVENTORY, MOVE FARTHER SOUTH, OR EXPLORE.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,FARTHER,EXPLORE)");
       }

       choice = scan.nextLine();
       if(choice.equals("EAST")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED EAST AND STOPPED BY A DIRTY STREAM.\nIT'S FILLED WITH GARBAGE, BUT THERE ARE ALSO PLASTIC BOTTLES.\nSHOULD I FILL THEM WITH WATER OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: FILL,MOVE)");
       }

       choice = scan.nextLine();
       if(choice.equals("WEST")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED WEST AND FOUND AN ABANDONED SHACK.\nSHOULD I SEARCH IT FOR LOOT OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: SEARCH,MOVE)");}
       }

       choice = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Tested. Works near perfectly.

Comment: Don't sprinkle `{}` randomly in your code. Learn to format/indent it properly, and do that before posting.

Comment: yes, but not how I want it to. that's why I posted it on here.

Comment: @Mat I'd take your advice, if I knew how. I'd like to be working on this, not researching (if that sounds ignorant of me, pardon), but if the yearn to see results boils in me like it does in you guys, you'll know what i'm saying.

Comment: Format your code next time before posting and when coding! It is not possible to read this code.

Comment: Do not use Notepad++, there are many IDE´s for Java development, take one.

Comment: @tak3shi If I use Notepad++, it works fine. I use Netbeans, errors pop up like catholic rabbits. Like i've mentioned, I'm semi-rusty at java, and I believe notepad++ is a good starting program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have come from a procedural language like Basic/Pascal.

To allow extension and more rooms you should break out the functionality into classes.

Location - Details the location the player is in

Exit - A valid exit from the room (added to an exits list in the location)

Item - any Item in the room or inventory

Command - Possibly the Superclass of Exit detailing what can be done with something.

This is just a starting idea. You can then have a file containing the rooms etc that is loaded at start time, this way you can use the one engine to make multiple RPG levels/adventures. (you could even link in Graphics and sounds)

If you want to take a look at how something like TinyMuck (C/C++) does its stuff, you may get a better idea - There is a Java version of a MUD/MUCK out there which is heavily Object orientated.

On another note this is a cleaned up version of your code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class XOBYT
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String choice;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("COPYRIGHT 2016 HARBNGER STUDIOS\nYou wake up in a broken-down alabaster\nhouse with no knowledge of who\nyou are or where you came from.\nWhich direction do you want to head? (options: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST)");
        choice = scan.nextLine();
        if(choice.equals("NORTH")){System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED NORTH TO A RUN-DOWN VILLAGE. CARCASSES EVERYWHERE.\nNO SURVIVORS. I WONDER WHAT HAPPENED HERE.\nI LOOTED THE BODIES, TALOS BLESS MY SOUL. I FOUND A PISTOL AND SOME GAUZE. I CAN VIEW MY INVENTORY, HIT THE ROAD, OR LINGER AROUND.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,ROAD,LINGER)");}
            choice = scan.nextLine();
        if(choice.equals("INVENTORY")){
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644\n\nI TRAVELED SOUTH AND STOPPED AT AN ABANDONED\nOUTPOST. IT HAS SOME SUPPLIES. I PICKED\nUP A PISTOL AND SOME NANITE SYRINGES. I CAN CHECK\nMY INVENTORY, MOVE FARTHER SOUTH, OR EXPLORE.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,FARTHER,EXPLORE)");}
        choice = scan.nextLine();
        if(choice.equals("FARTHER")){
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED EAST AND STOPPED BY A DIRTY STREAM.\nIT'S FILLED WITH GARBAGE, BUT THERE ARE ALSO PLASTIC BOTTLES.\nSHOULD I FILL THEM WITH WATER OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: FILL,MOVE)");}
        choice = scan.nextLine();
        if(choice.equals("EXPLORE")){
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED WEST AND FOUND AN ABANDONED SHACK.\nSHOULD I SEARCH IT FOR LOOT OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: SEARCH,MOVE)");}}
        choice = scan.nextLine();

        if(choice.equals("SOUTH")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644\n\nI TRAVELED SOUTH AND STOPPED AT AN ABANDONED\nOUTPOST. IT HAS SOME SUPPLIES. I PICKED\nUP A PISTOL AND SOME NANITE SYRINGES. I CAN CHECK\nMY INVENTORY, MOVE FARTHER SOUTH, OR EXPLORE.\n\n(options: INVENTORY,FARTHER,EXPLORE)");}
        choice = scan.nextLine();
        if(choice.equals("EAST")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED EAST AND STOPPED BY A DIRTY STREAM.\nIT'S FILLED WITH GARBAGE, BUT THERE ARE ALSO PLASTIC BOTTLES.\nSHOULD I FILL THEM WITH WATER OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: FILL,MOVE)");}
        choice = scan.nextLine();
        if(choice.equals("WEST")){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n--TERMINAL_LOG--\n\nI FOUND THIS HANDHELD TERMINAL LOG FIGURED I'D\nPUT IT TO SOME USE. TODAY IS, ACCORDING TO THIS, THE 15TH OF JAN, 2644.\n\nI TRAVELED WEST AND FOUND AN ABANDONED SHACK.\nSHOULD I SEARCH IT FOR LOOT OR MOVE ON?\n\n(options: SEARCH,MOVE)");}}
       choice = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

Which by the way doesnt have any sort of loop to loop round to do the command over and over.

Comment: I see... So make separate classes for the rooms, exit, etc... how would you do that? How could you define the rooms? Sorry for the inconvenience... just trying to get into Calculus while learning Arithmetic.

Comment: I think a better way would be for you to look at how this project does it https://github.com/ProjectMoon/ringmud  They store the Rooms and descriptions etc in a database/config file. So for instance ROOM,1,This is a barren Desert, you can see {items} and there is {exits} exits\nROOM,2, The portal to infinity, You are dead\nEXIT,1,a shimmering portal,You can see a shimmering portal with strange images inside,1,2\n    The Exit Definition is exit id,short desc,look desc,room exit is in,room exit goes to

Comment: There are other parameters you can add, but i will let you work it out

Comment: Thank you. This helped tremendously.

Comment: So would you do something like `private static void room(String name, String description){
         System.out.println(name + "\n"+description);
     }`

Comment: public class Room { private List<Exit> exits; private List<Item> items; public Room() {} }   - just as starters

Comment: For each room? or do it just for one, but then copy the brackets?

Comment: Think Objects, if you are having problems think noun/verb - Nouns are either Classes or Parameters in classes, Verbs are actions (methods) Usually If it is a physical item it will be a class, so you have a Room, Exit, Item, Player, Monster etc, but Name is a property

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bugging you, but this is helping a lot. So, verbs (methods) are actions, therefore go into the XOBYT class. The rooms, however, you say to put them into a different class. The "`public class Room { private List<Exit> exits; private List<Item> items; public Room() {} }`" yet, what would go in the blanks? would I have to rewrite my whole file? Could you give me an example room and then apply it to the XOBYT class above? My apologies for the barrage of questions, but it would help a lot.

Comment: Also, I'm working on this with a friend. You said something about an "Item" definition. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619255/i-need-assistance-with-an-rpg-type-inventory-java is his thread, but it focuses way more on "INVENTORY".

Comment: in the Mud / Muck world Everything can contain everything else, so you can have a Room in an item, with that item in a player (inventory) then that player in a room, which could be in another room or even in the player himself, The exits are what provide the movement from one place to another. and move the player to the location of the object linked on the exit. so you would have a Generic AbstractMuckObject which has some basic parameters added (everything has a short and long description and a link to a location) in Mucks Room 0 is the start of the universe and everything else is based in it

Comment: I think you need to sort out how to program properly in java before both of you proceed, its a fun idea but you need to separate the Engine from the content, that is your first problem, MVC is a good pattern to follow, the Content is the Model, View is the screen, so you need to create the Engine (controller) which processes commands and sends descriptions to the view

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry about my incorrect answer before. I took another look and I don't think those if-statements are nested. The NORTH if statement ends immediately after the print statement. So if you don't say north, it won't skip over the if-statements which pertain to asking about the actions.

Also, I think your problem is that what happens is when you don't say inventory, it doesn't crash. It is actually just asking for another input. But because there is no prompt, it looks like it's not doing anything.

I think the code should look something like this: (you should edit it to fit your purposes, of course)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String choice;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("text");
  choice = scan.nextLine();
  if(choice.equals("NORTH")){
    System.out.println("text");
    choice = scan.nextLine();
    if(choice.equals("INVENTORY")){
      System.out.println("text");
    }

    if(choice.equals("FARTHER")){
      System.out.println("text");
    }

    if(choice.equals("EXPLORE")){
      System.out.println("text");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I'd still have to put the "choice =" every "if" statement, correct?

Comment: @Similar Paradox nope. You only need one input right after the user picks north. Then the program checks that input against multiple possibilities. Otherwise it would ask the user for input many times. Also, I would recommend adding an else-statement at the end to handle with what happens if the user mistypes a command.